# Demo response different from runtime response

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I'm trying to use the Google Cloud Vision API to OCR this image:

[image: sample]

I'm using the following code the make the request:

```
const resp = await fetch(
  `https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=${KEY}`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      requests: [{
        image: {content: encoded},
        features: [{type: "TEXT_DETECTION"}],
      }]
    }),
});
```

This works but there is some information missing from the result. If we look at the `text` field:

```
Dog Search
D G O OD D ODG O O D D O
O D O O G G G D O D G OG G
OGD GOGD GO G GO G D
D D D G D DO DOO G D O O
O DGOGG D O O G G O O D
DOG
```

Here's that visualized:

[image: 1]

There are boxes around the characters which were recognized. But, if we put this image into the gcv [demo application](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/drag-and-drop), we get this instead:

[image: 2]
And this is what `text` looks like:

```
Dog Search
D GOOD D 0 D GOOD DO
0 D 0 0 G G G DOD GO GG
o G O G D 0 0 D G 0 0 D D D
D G D o o o G G o o G D Go
0 G D G O G D G O G G O G D
D D D G D DO DO O G D 0 0
O D GO G G D 0 0 G G 0 0 D
DOG
```

Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/0xcaff/d06828a6d17653043c1a0531c317aef1) with the requests + responses. I'm authenticating using a API token.

Why are the responses different? The requests are slightly different but not in a way which should affect the output. Right?

Comment: Here's a similar question without a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44362759/google-cloud-vision-demo-behaving-differently-from-actual-api

Comment: I'm an idiot. This is a duplicate of the other question. The answer by class is correct. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44362759/google-cloud-vision-demo-behaving-differently-from-actual-api

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Cloud vision demo behaving differently from actual API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44362759/google-cloud-vision-demo-behaving-differently-from-actual-api)